# Go Router browser navigation buttons won't work

Tags: flutter

In work we are using Go router for our app navigation. It is a web and mobile.

The question is: We have a sidebar with options. When click on one, the navigator navigates and changes the URL, and the back and forward buttons from the browser are activeted.

Te problem is, these buttons wont work, for example:

Page A has a context.push("PageB") --> URL changes to PageB --> Click on backward botton from browser --> URL changes back to PageA, but pageA is not drawn, we are still seeing pageB, just the URL has changed.

This happens with go and push.

Any ideas? If there is something you may need, ask me.

I tried a bunch of things, like playing with de key and parentKey.